# Qt IDE c/c++Debugger mode is Very Slow?

Tags: qt

I'm using the Qt for developing the c/c++ application,while i try to debug the app with static library it is very slow and takes much time step over (r) in..

can any one suggest me to make the debugger fast as like vs2008..

regards
VS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely you are having this behaviour because the debugger retrieves required debug info for system libraries from the internet each time - or it doesn't find the requested info at all. If so, it will display something like that in the Debugging Window.

Follow these steps to set up a symbol cache which will allow caching debug symbols:

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html#setting-cdb-paths-on-windows

This might still make it slow for the next time you debug, but it should get quite fast from the second time on.

If you do not have internet access though, you will need to manually download these symbols from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx

and place them in the symbol cache folder you specified.

Comment: thanks for your reply,and its working for windows,but i'm asking for linux ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: @vigneshwaransekar yes, it's unbearably slow on Linux. I'm waiting 15 seconds sometimes to single step trivial lines on a Core I7 Extreme @ 3.46GHz. It slows exponentially in relationship to the number of local variables. A few variables and it's instant, beyond that, unbearable.

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 3):

it has nothing to do with windows and debug symbols server
this is happening when libqt has debug symbols and it happens even (directly) in gdb/cgdb!
it has to do with dwarf (still looking into this one)
regressed on windows (8), ubuntu (13.04), fedora (19-rc) & mac (10.8.5 & 10.9) -> obviously has little to do with os or library

Comment: I'll need this on Windows Vista !!! I'm building with MinGW, and after the switch to Qt5 debugger it's totally unusable. Was ok with 4.8. You'll report your outcome here ?