# gdb doesn't resume after breakpoint. MITK-Framewok Project using Qt-Creator, gdb, Linux Mint 15

Tags: qt, qt4, gdb, qt-creator, mitk

I'm writing plugin for the MITK framework using Qt-Creator with gdb on Linux-Mint 15.
Resuming after halting at any breakpoint doesn't work, or seems to take upwards of 30 minutes (every time). My project is not very big however, so there's no way I've got the debugger set up correctly.

I've got the Qt 4.8 and 5.01 packages installed. MITK requires Qt4 and I believe to have it specified everywhere in the makefiles.

I do get the following output when starting to debug:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Unpassender IOCTL (I/O-Control) f\303\274r das Ger\303\244t\n"
no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
```

From other answers on this site I get that the first line can be ignored...
Can anyone say if the second line is related to my problem and possibly how?

I wonder if this could have to do with there being two versions of Qt installed on my pc - I dont know how to get Qt5 completely off the system with all its packages though...

One user mentioned this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256365/2561709
Its all I could really find but I dont understand it, any clues?

I'd appreciate any hint at a possible cause of the problem. Please tell me what other relevant information I could provide, thanks!